# Redux dev tools extension exports failing "Failed: Network error"

Tags: google-chrome, redux, redux-devtools

Using the Redux Dev Tools extension, I am receiving errors when exporting any time after I have interacted with my app. If I do a fresh page load and export, it works, but after one or sometimes a couple of state changes, I receive "Failed: Network error" from Chrome instead of a download.

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same error, but have also been unable to find a solution. Did you find anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But if I do, I will update this question. If I reload the page it works, but that defeats the whole purpose :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your state(s) size is probably too big. I started cleanup unused data from state, and Export stopped failing.

Try also "Commit" to view/get only the last state.

Comment: I no longer have access to the codebase that was causing this issue, can someone with the same issue give this a try and see if this solves the issue and report back?

Comment: Does for me!  Thanks.